# Select Item in Combobox which text is like Timespan in DateTime WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, combobox, datepicker

I have a `DateTime` variable with a date and a time in it. Now I want to get the date out of that variable to be shown in my `DatePicker`. The time of that `DateTime` variable I want to filter out, and select the corresponding in a `ComboBox` populated with time values.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Let's say my `DateTime` variable has the value of `{15.06.2016 10:00:00}`. Now I want the `DatePicker` to show `15.06.2016`. And I want to automatically select that item in the `ComboBox` which has `10:00` in it.

Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
MyCombobox.SelectedValue = myDate.ToString("HH:mm");
```